# Pinescript Count Moving Averages Above or Below Close

Tags: pine-script

I'm sure this is simple but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to count how many moving averages are above or below the close.

I am trying to add these two results into a table:

example: close $50

(2) Moving averages above close
(3) Moving averages below close

200 MA $70
100 MA $55
50 MA $45
20 MA $40
10 MA $29

Any help would be great thanks.

I have tries sum with not luck

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
ema100 = ta.ema(close, 100)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)

 
c200 = ema200 > close ? 10 : 1 
c100 = ema100 > close ? 10 : 1 
c50 = ema50 > close ? 10 : 1 
c20 = ema20 > close ? 10 : 1 
c10 = ema10 > close ? 10 : 1 
    
count = c200 + c100 + c50 + c20 + c10
above = math.floor(count/10)
below = count - above*10

label.new(bar_index, high, "above: " + str.tostring(above) + "\nbelow: " + str.tostring(below), color = color.yellow)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very much appreciated. all the best!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Would be grateful if you could accept the answer.